# How do I open a folder browser dialog from a PowerShell script?

Tags: powershell, openfiledialog, folderbrowserdialog

I have a PS1 script which opens a FolderBrowserDialog:

*open-folder.ps1*

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms

Push-Location
$FileBrowser = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog -Property @{
  ShowNewFolderButton = $true
  Description = 'Select folder...'
  RootFolder = 'Desktop'
}
if($FileBrowser.ShowDialog() -ne "OK") {
  exit
}
Pop-Location

$Location = $FileBrowser.SelectedPath

Write-Host "Chose $Location"
```

[image: FolderBrowserDialog]

This UI is hard to use and does not offer as much functionality as explorer.

*How do I launch a folder browser which uses the same UI as the OpenFileDialog, but only allows the user to select folders?*

Example of the OpenFileDialog (allows selection of files, which is not wanted):

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms

Push-Location
$FileBrowser = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog -Property @{
  Title = 'Select folder...'
}
if($FileBrowser.ShowDialog() -ne "OK") {
  exit
}
Pop-Location

$Location = $FileBrowser.FileName

Write-Host "Chose $Location"
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You may try to open dialog with this property:

```
Filter = 'Folders|*.'
```

It only shows Folders and Files without extension

Answer (score 0):

I think if you run it using PowerShell 7 it has a better interface.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Windows Powershell, it does not seem to be possible to change the UI of the folder dialogue browser. I tried your code using Powershell 7.2.6 and the UI looked the same as what you are trying to achieve.

[screencapture of the result of your original code using Powershell 7.2.6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZahXA.png)

I also tried a few other different dialogue scripts with the same results.

Here is a link to read about migrating from Windows Powershell to Powershell, the differences between the two, and how to use them optimally.

[Migrating from Windows Powershell to Powershell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/whats-new/migrating-from-windows-powershell-51-to-powershell-7)

Comment: Thanks for the comment, there is no link to the thing to read

Comment: Thank you @MHebes for bringing that to my attention.  I have edited to include the link.